# How to Implement Base Adapter class containing multiple hash map lists

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I am developing android application and i want to implement Base Adapter class with multiple array list . But i have no idea to implement here is my code given below .In my Activity class this is adapter object
            adapter = new Dashboard_Adapter(mContext, arrayList,arrayList_prsndata,arrayList_Comnt,arrayList_pics,arrayList_Feddta);

```
public class Dashboard_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater = null;
    ArrayList<String> arr;
    private Activity activity;
    public Context context;
    HashMap<String, String> threadmap;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_prsndata;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_Comnt;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_pics;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_Feddta;
    public Dashboard_Adapter(Context dashbord, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayLis, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_prsndata, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_Comnt, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_pics, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arrayList_Feeddta) {
        activity = (Activity) dashbord;
        this.arrayList =arrayLis;
        this.arrayList_prsndata =arrayList_prsndata;
        this.arrayList_Comnt =arrayList_Comnt;
        this.arrayList_pics =arrayList_pics;
        this.arrayList_Feddta =arrayList_Feeddta;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        sharedPreferences = activity.getSharedPreferences(Login.My_Prefs, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        final ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.newpost, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.Name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTags);
            viewHolder.PageName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPageName);
            viewHolder.Time = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvtimeShow);
            viewHolder.Disc = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.disc);
            viewHolder.PostText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPost);
            viewHolder.PostImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgPost);
            viewHolder.PostVideo = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.videoPost);
            viewHolder.btnLike = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTotalLike);
            viewHolder.btnDisLike = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTotalDislikes);
            viewHolder.btnComment = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTotalComment);
            viewHolder.btnShare = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnTotalShares);
            viewHolder.btnPromote = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFeedResponce);
            viewHolder.btnGreatJobNumber = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnGreatJobNumber);

            //  viewHolder.btnup.setTag(position);

            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }
        threadmap = new HashMap<>();
        threadmap = arrayList.get(position);
        viewHolder.btnLike.setText(threadmap.get(Dashboard.like_count));
        viewHolder.btnDisLike.setText(threadmap.get(Dashboard.unlike_count));
        viewHolder.btnComment.setText(threadmap.get(Dashboard.comment_count));
        viewHolder.btnShare.setText(threadmap.get(Dashboard.share_count));
        viewHolder.btnPromote.setText(threadmap.get(Dashboard.feed_count));
        viewHolder.btnGreatJobNumber.setText(threadmap.get(Dashboard.greatjob_count));
        return view;
        // Glide.with(context).load(images).placeholder(R.drawable.home).into(imageView);
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        TextView Name;
        TextView PageName;
        TextView Time;
        TextView Disc;
        TextView PostText;
        ImageView PostImage;
        VideoView PostVideo;
        Button btnLike;
        Button btnDisLike;
        Button btnComment;
        Button btnShare;
        Button btnPromote;
        Button btnGreatJobNumber;

    }

}
```

Comment: start using a model class

Comment: How please explain. i need to show data in list view.from all list